# how to add layers in ggplot using a for-loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot each column of a dataframe to a separate layer in ggplot2.
Building the plot layer by layer works well:

```
df<-data.frame(x1=c(1:5),y1=c(2.0,5.4,7.1,4.6,5.0),y2=c(0.4,9.4,2.9,5.4,1.1),y3=c(2.4,6.6,8.1,5.6,6.3))

ggplot(data=df,aes(df[,1]))+geom_line(aes(y=df[,2]))+geom_line(aes(y=df[,3]))
```

Is there a way to plot all available columns at ones by using a single function?

I tried to do it this way but it does not work:

```
    plotAllLayers<-function(df){
    p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(df[,1]))
    for(i in seq(2:ncol(df))){ 
        p<-p+geom_line(aes(y=df[,i]))
        }
        return(p)
    }

plotAllLayers(df)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One approach would be to reshape your data frame from wide format to long format using function `melt()` from library `reshape2`. In new data frame you will have `x1` values, `variable` that determine from which column data came, and `value` that contains all original y values.

Now you can plot all data with one `ggplot()` and `geom_line()` call and use `variable` to have for example separate color for each line.

```
 library(reshape2)
 df.long<-melt(df,id.vars="x1")
 head(df.long)
  x1 variable value
1  1       y1   2.0
2  2       y1   5.4
3  3       y1   7.1
4  4       y1   4.6
5  5       y1   5.0
6  1       y2   0.4
 ggplot(df.long,aes(x1,value,color=variable))+geom_line()
```

[image]

If you really want to use for() loop (not the best way) then you should use `names(df)[-1]` instead of `seq()`. This will make vector of column names (except first column). Then inside `geom_line()` use `aes_string(y=i)` to select column by their name.

```
plotAllLayers<-function(df){
  p<-ggplot(data=df,aes(df[,1]))
  for(i in names(df)[-1]){ 
    p<-p+geom_line(aes_string(y=i))
  }
  return(p)
}

plotAllLayers(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answers my Question. It really helps. 
 reshape2 is very useful. I guess that I have to get used to the long format.

Answer (score 10):

I tried the melt method on a large messy dataset and wished for a faster, cleaner method. This for loop uses eval() to build the desired plot.

```
fields <- names(df_normal) # index, var1, var2, var3, ...

p <- ggplot( aes(x=index), data = df_normal)
for (i in 2:length(fields)) { 
  loop_input = paste("geom_smooth(aes(y=",fields[i],",color='",fields[i],"'))", sep="")
  p <- p + eval(parse(text=loop_input))  
}
p <- p + guides( color = guide_legend(title = "",) )
p
```

This ran a lot faster then a large melted dataset when I tested.

I also tried the for loop with aes_string(y=fields[i], color=fields[i]) method, but couldn't get the colors to be differentiated.

Comment: The only answer to this question that I have seen that really loops and actually works.  Granted many consider 'eval' a cardinal sin, but it exists for a reason :P

Comment: Thank you!! As a note to later visitors, I found that assigning data to a variable using the iterator (e.g. `subset_of_data <- some_data_frame[i]`) doesn't seem to work. Instead of adding more and more components to `p`, only the last one seems to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

For the OP's situation, I think `pivot_longer` is best.  But today I had a situation that did not seem amenable to pivoting, so I used the following code to create layers programmatically.  I did not need to use `eval()`.

```
data_tibble <- tibble(my_var = c(650, 1040, 1060, 1150, 1180, 1220, 1280, 1430, 1440, 1440, 1470, 1470, 1480, 1490, 1520, 1550, 1560, 1560, 1600, 1600, 1610, 1630, 1660, 1740, 1780, 1800, 1810, 1820, 1830, 1870, 1910, 1910, 1930, 1940, 1940, 1940, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2060, 2080, 2080, 2090, 2100, 2120, 2140, 2160, 2240, 2260, 2320, 2430, 2440, 2540, 2550, 2560, 2570, 2610, 2660, 2680, 2700, 2700, 2720, 2730, 2790, 2820, 2880, 2910, 2970, 2970, 3030, 3050, 3060, 3080, 3120, 3160, 3200, 3280, 3290, 3310, 3320, 3340, 3350, 3400, 3430, 3540, 3550, 3580, 3580, 3620, 3640, 3650, 3710, 3820, 3820, 3870, 3980, 4060, 4070, 4160, 4170, 4170, 4220, 4300, 4320, 4350, 4390, 4430, 4450, 4500, 4650, 4650, 5080, 5160, 5160, 5460, 5490, 5670, 5680, 5760, 5960, 5980, 6060, 6120, 6190, 6480, 6760, 7750, 8390, 9560))

# This is a normal histogram
plot <- data_tibble %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=my_var, y = ..density..))

# We prepare layers to add
stat_layers <- tibble(distribution = c("lognormal", "gamma", "normal"),
                     fun = c(dlnorm, dgamma, dnorm),
                     colour = c("red", "green", "yellow")) %>% 
  mutate(args = map(distribution, MASS::fitdistr, x=data_tibble$my_var)) %>% 
  mutate(args = map(args, ~as.list(.$estimate))) %>% 
  select(-distribution) %>% 
  pmap(stat_function)

# Final Plot
plot + stat_layers
```

The idea is that you organize a tibble with the arguments that you want to plug into a geom/stat function.  Each row should correspond to a `+` layer that you want to add to the ggplot.  Then use `pmap`.  This creates a list of layers that you can simply add to your plot.

Answer (score 2):

Reshaping your data so you don't need the loop is the best option. Otherwise with newer versions of ggplot, you can use the `.data` pronoun inside the `aes()`. You can do

```
plotAllLayers<-function(df){
    p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(df[,1]))
    for(i in names(df)[2:ncol(df)]){ 
        p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=.data[[i]]))
    }
    return(p)
}
plotAllLayers(df)
```

We use the `.data` pronoun to get at the data passed to the `ggplot` object, and we iterate over the column names because `.data` doesn't like indexes for some reason.