# How can I plot a distribution for different values of a parameter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following script:

```
library(ggplot2)

values <- c(0.1,0.15,0.2,0.3,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5)
colours <- palette()[1:length(values)];


p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 2)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 0.1),aes(colour="0.1"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 0.15),aes(colour="0.15"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 0.2),aes(colour="0.2"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 0.3),aes(colour="0.3"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 0.5),aes(colour="0.5"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 1),aes(colour="1"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 1.5),aes(colour="1.5"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 2),aes(colour="2"))+
  stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = 2.5),aes(colour="2.5"))+
  scale_colour_manual("Sigma:", values=colours, breaks=as.character(values))

p
```

Which produces the following graph (minus the title) of how the log-normal distribution looks like for different values of a parameter:

[image: graph of log-normal distribution]

How can I replace those copy-pasted lines with something more eye-friendly?

Something like `stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = values),aes(colour=as.character(values)))`

Edit: Unlike the question that was suggested as duplicate, I'm handling functions, not data, so I'm not sure how to apply the suggestions there

---

I also tried in a for-loop like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

values <- c(0.1,0.15,0.2,0.3,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5)
colours <- palette()[1:length(values)];


p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 2)), aes(x)) +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Log-normaal distributie met verschillende waarden van ", sigma)))+
  ylab(expression(paste(f[X](x)))) 


for(i in 1:length(values)){
  p <- p + stat_function(fun= function(x) dlnorm(x,mean = 0, sd = values[i]), aes(colour=as.character(values[i])))
}


p +   scale_colour_manual("Sigma:", values=colours, breaks=as.character(values))
```

But it doesn't work: it only plots the last curve.

---

I also tried as the an answer suggested, which works fine, but I'm then unable to add labels to the colours:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 2)), aes(x)) + 
  mapply(function(col, mean, sd) {
    stat_function(fun = dlnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd), aes(colour=col))}, 
    mean = 0, sd = values, col = as.character(values)) +
  scale_colour_manual("Sigma:", values=colours, breaks=as.character(values))
```

It produces an error saying: 
`Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add layers in ggplot using a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987367/how-to-add-layers-in-ggplot-using-a-for-loop)

Comment: @LAP: I saw that question, but couldn't make it work. I don't have data, but rather continuous curves plotted from a function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```r
library(ggplot2)

values <- c(0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)
colours <- c(palette(), "orange");

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 2)), aes(x)) + 
  mapply(function(col, mean, sd) {
    stat_function(fun = dlnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd), colour = col)}, 
    mean = 0, sd = values, col = colours)
```

**Edit update:** 
Seems if you want to have color legend with `stat_function` then you need to *repeat it multiple times* rather than putting it in `for` loop or `mapply`.

Just in case you are interested in another solution then you may try below chunk of code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(mean = rep(0,9),
                 sd = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5))
colours <- c(palette(), "orange");

x <- seq(0,2,0.01)
my_func <- mdply(df, function(mean,sd){
  data.frame(x=x, y=dlnorm(x,mean, sd), sigma=as.character(sd))}) %>% 
  bind_rows

ggplot(my_func, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=sigma)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=colours) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Output plot]

Comment: That helps indeed, however it breaks when I try to add labels for the colours (see edited question)